# Eureka + Zuul + Spring Cloud Config Server + HTTPS problem

Tags: spring, https, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-config

I am developing an application using the microservice architecture. I am using Spring Cloud Eureka and Spring Cloud Zuul. I am also using Cloud Config Server because I want to add routes dynamically to Zuul Gateway. I am having problems with Cloud Config Server. It is registred with the Eureka Server (I see an instance of it in the Eureka Dashboard), but when I run Zuul Gateway, for example, I get an exception

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances found of configserver
>   (cloud-config-server)"

and the microservice shuts down after that. The problem started after the implementation of the HTTPS protocol. The same configuration of microservices and the config server was working fine before that.

[image]

This is the Eureka application.yml file:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    securePort: ${server.port}
    securePortEnabled: true  
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false 
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/
    statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/admin/info
server:
  port: 8761
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: service-registry
    key-store: classpath:service-registry.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: JKS
    trust-store: classpath:service-registry.jks
    trust-store-password: password
    trust-store-type: JKS
```

This is the Zuul application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8762
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:zuul-gateway.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias: zuul-gateway
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
    statusPageUrl: https://localhost:${server.port}/info
    healthCheckUrl: https://localhost:${server.port}/health
    homePageUrl: https://localhost:${server.port}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone:  ${EUREKA_URI:https://localhost:8761/eureka}
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    mock-bitcoin-service:
      service-id: mock-bitcoin-service
      path: /mock-bitcoin-service/**
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 5000000
    socket-timeout-millis: 5000000
  ignoredServices: '*'

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 12000
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 10000
  ReadTimeout: 10000
```

Here is the Spring Cloud Config Server application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8888
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:cloud-config-server.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias: cloud-config-server
    key-store-type: JKS
    trust-store: classpath:cloud-config-server.jks
    trust-store-password: password
    trust-store-type: JKS
eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
    statusPageUrl: https://localhost:${server.port}/info
    healthCheckUrl: https://localhost:${server.port}/health
    homePageUrl: https://localhost:${server.port}
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 20
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 10
  client:
    enabled: true
    instance-info-replication-interval-seconds: 10
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 10
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone:  ${EUREKA_URI:https://localhost:8761/eureka}
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          clone-on-start: true
          search-paths: /config/{application}
          uri: https://github.com/XXXX.git
```

**Question**:
Has anyone encountered this kind of problem before and does anyone know how can I solve it?